# iOS Auto Layout: Distribute remaining space of a superview to its subviews

Tags: layout, ios6, uikit, autolayout

With iOS Auto-Layout each element inside a superview can have a relative size (e.g. element A is twice as wide as element B, element C is half as wide as element A...).

What I want to do differs a bit from the approach described above.

Imagine each element has an absolute width. The sum of all widths is less then the width of their superview. According to the element's weight value (A.weight = 2; B.weight=1; C.weight = 1;), I would like to distribute the remaining space. Is their any possibility to get the remaining space, although the width of the superview is unknown?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's say you have a superview that's 100 pixels wide and contains subviews A, B, and C.  A's weight is 2, B's weight is 1, and C's weight is 1. How wide should A, B, and C be?

Comment: Forget to say that the size of the superview is unknown. Sorry!

Comment: **Let's say** the superview's width is 100 points. How wide do you want A, B, and C be?

Comment: A.width = 15px, B.width = 25px, C.width= 10px

Comment: Shouldn't your 3 subviews' widths add up to 100 points/pixels? And why are B's & C's widths different when their weights are the same?

Comment: the sum of the widths is 50px. just in case the superview is 100px wide, there would be another 50px to distribute to the elements according to their weight.